# Does anyone know this LCD display?

Tags: identification, lcd

In the interest of recycling old components, I was searching my 'junk-box' for a small display for a project and found this one. The size would be ideal...

I don't know the origin, but I'm intrigued that it only has 8 pins, which would be great as I have precious few pins left on the processor. Maybe it uses SPI or I2C or other serial programming. Also, the placement of the pins does not suggest parallel access.

I suspect it's a custom display though, as I could find nothing on the 'net:

- I suspect it's backlighted
- The visible area measures about 32 x 16mm (1 ¼" by ⅝")
- on the side 82B01 (probably a manufacturing code?), III-V was the manufacturer (which I believe disappeared years ago), 9000095-1 - no luck.
- on the PC board, HY212 or HY21294VO resulted in nothing relatable.
  [image: Front view]
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: The main LCD driver chip is under the black circular blob. It's possibly a custom chip anyway so I doubt the number would help.

Comment: That's another name which makes finding information absolutely horrible. III-V Systems is a very common topic in semiconductor technology. So everything pops up but not that company...

Comment: Bend those four tabs and see if there's anything else on the inside.  So far, found nothing relevant for all those numbers.  Maybe can at least determine if two of the pins are for the backlight.

Comment: @Arsenal I tried "LCD manufacturers Philippines" and "lcd company in philippines", they throw up a number of online trade directories, but none of them list III-V Systems.

Comment: The "hy" mark next to "HY-212 94VO" looks like a manufacturer's logo.  Couldn't find it in the usual places.

Comment: Arsenal, Theodore, I found a reference to III-V in a financial (the places Google takes us), and there was a description of the company, describing LCD fabrication, and bad financial decisions.

Comment: @rdrsc, Normally those tabs delicately press the display with conductive strips onto the PCB. It's not always that easy to reconstruct afterwards. If no other info appears, I'll go that path.